# Grails Data Modelling dilemma

Tags: sql, database-design, grails, polymorphism, data-modeling

I'm hoping someone can help me decide the best way to model this design for what sounds like should be a simple use case.

I have a `Client` domain class. I have a `Person` command object and a `Firm` command object which represents either a firm or an organization.

I also have subclasses, lets call them for `ClientSubClass1` and `ClientSubClass2` for the sake of naming, that both extend `Client`.

Where I'm puzzled is that a client should be able to be either a person or a firm.

So the best way forward I feel is to use embedding and embed both a Firm class and Person class into the Client class and add a flag that indicates whether the client is a person or firm. 
Otherwise I can't see how to use inheritance to accomplish what I need.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why can't person and firm just extend a base client class?

Comment: There will be other classes that could also extend Person or Firm but not be a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just to answer this question and wrap it up, I decided to create a higher level Contact domain class, which has a Person and Organization sub class (tableperHierarchy false).

A Client extends Person and contains an embedded Organization, and a flag to indicate whether when referring to that Client I should use the Person details or the Organization details, for instances such as when I want to display the name of the client, I know whether to use the personal name (title, forename, initials, surname) or the firm name from the embedded Organization.

Within the Contact class definition I also use an embedded Address class, held in 'src/groovy' so it doesn't create its own table.

So I have a mixture of composition and inheritance which work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails you can use inheritance in your domain classes, and GORM will create and manage a flag in the database for you without you needing to explicitly declare one. I would create Person and Firm domain classes that inherit from Client.

Command classes are mainly useful for binding parameters in requests to controller actions, which is somewhat unrelated to how your data is stored and retrieved.

Comment: I think they(CommandObjects) also should be used when you want to reuse common structures (including constraints) e.g. an Address, however don't want to have Addresses in their own table.